# WHERE id IN doesn't work in UPDATE

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-error-1242

`UPDATE statistics`'
`SET money = money + '$money'` 
`WHERE member_id IN`
 `((SELECT member_id FROM races WHERE l_id = '$mem_id'), $other_id)`

What's wrong with that? I want to retrieve all member_ids from races and also include to member_id $other_id. Without $other_id it works.

By the way, it gives me "Subquery returns more than 1 row" error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try with:

```
UPDATE statistics
   SET money = money + $money
 WHERE member_id IN (
       SELECT member_id
         FROM races
        WHERE l_id = $mem_id 
       )
    OR member_id = $other_id
```

And suggestion - for `int` type columns do not use apostrophs.

Comment: "for int type columns do not use apostrophs."
I have protected it with addslashes() function, so I think it is okay, isn't?

Comment: For strings - ok, but I preffer `mysql_escape_string()`.
If you work with ints, floats, etc - cast them  `$id = (int) $_GET['id'];` (or `(float)`, etc) and it will be enough.

Answer (score 4):

subquery returns member_id and $other_id

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it:

```
(SELECT member_id FROM races WHERE l_id = '$mem_id'
UNION
SELECT $other_id)
```